# Spark-shell running a SELECT for a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've created a spark scala script to load a file with customers information. Then I have created a case class to map the records and show them up as a table, my script below:

```
//spark context
sc
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

//Define the class to map customers coming from the data inputh
case class customer (cusid: Int, name: String, city : String, province: String, postalcode: String)

//load the file info
val customer_file = sc.textFile("file:////home/ingenieroandresangel/scalascripts/customer.txt")
val customer_rdd = customer_file.map(_.split(",")).map(p => customer(p(0).toInt,p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4)))

val cusstomerdf = customer_rdd.toDF()
```

current results:
[image: enter image desperformon here]

Now, I need to perform spark sql queries to get back just a column coming from my dataframe, example the column name:

print(cusstomerdf.select("name"))

Nevertheless, the results are not as expected. I need to get back the rows for the column name but instead, I get this  result:

[image]

Question: How should I run the right select to get back just the column name on my dataframe??  thanks

Comment: Please read the doc to know about the transformation operation. This operation only help get another dataframe.

Comment: @ashburshui thanks so much buddy I will to check out these concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The result is correct**. You are doing a *transformation* only as `select` is a *transformation*.

If you save it in a `parquet` file or a `csv` file you will see the result and can confirm that the `column` is already selected.

Meanwhile you can see the result on the screen by doing

```
val selecteddf = customerdf.select("name")
selecteddf.show(false)
```

which will show the *20 rows* of `name` `column`